# How can I execute multiple instructions for a when condition in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to execute multiple lines of execution for a `when` condition in Kotlin, **without** using an if-else statement. However, kotlin is complaining and returning an error. How can this be achieved? For example:

```kotlin
  when(studentAnswer2){
    quizAnswer2 -> points+=25
    quizAnswer2-1 -> 
      points += 20 
      println("The answer $studentAnswer2 is within 1 point of $quizAnswer2")
    quizAnswer2+1 -> 
      points += 20
      println("The answer $studentAnswer2 is within 1 point of $quizAnswer2")
  }
```

Does Kotlin provide this ability? Would I have to resort back to using an if-else statement?

Comment: You have to add { } after the -> if you are using more than 2 lines for a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add missing {} and else block

```
    when(studentAnswer2){
        quizAnswer2 -> points+=25
        quizAnswer2-1 -> {
            points += 20
            println("The answer $studentAnswer2 is within 1 point of $quizAnswer2")
        }
        quizAnswer2+1 -> {
            points += 20
            println("The answer $studentAnswer2 is within 1 point of $quizAnswer2")
        }
        else -> println("The answer $studentAnswer2 is not within 1 point of $quizAnswer2")
    }
```